# Dijkstra function for navigation for disadvantaged

Tags: coding, dijkstra

Is there a way we can write a function for Dijkstra to determine which node to enqueue and which to discard. This is for a navigation solution for people with disabilities where path to stairs may be shorter but not preferable to wheelchair bound individuals. The navigation solution should also support all individuals and only give a path discarding stairs if the specified user group is someone who is wheelchair bound etc. So basically i am attempting to write a function that checks if user group = wheelchair bound then removes the shortest path to stairs and gives the path to the nearest elevator. I am pretty new to this so any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lot's of edges (stairs) will be disabled in the graph for people with disabilities.
You can either filter them out before you build your graph (collection of edges), or add logic at 'calculating the tentative distances' step. (Step 3) in the [Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm)

Comment: That is where i am confused. How do I add that logic. More like what do I code in that logic to specifically ignore those edges.

Comment: At some point in your code you should have a collection of nodes and a collection of edges (with weights information) . It'll probably come from the db. You have to extend the edge class with an info whether it's disability accessible. In the simplest version it would be a boolean property. Then, before running the algorithm, you should go over all edges and remove all that are not disability accessible. And only after doing so, run the algorithm to find shortest path.

Answer (score 3):

Given that Dijkstra's algorithm requires a starting point (usually taken to be the person's current position), each run of the algorithm is already made specifically to the person's request. Because of this, you can prune the graph to remove edges that are inaccessible to that person (as DanielS already pointed out), before running the algorithm.

If you plan to use a pathfinding algorithm that uses some kind of precomputation, perhaps you can give more details about your plan, so that better answers can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you consider an edge for the first time in the algorithm, you determine which "distance" should be assumed for that edge. If the edge contains stairs, you adjust the "distance" accordingly, with much different adjustments for cars, bicycles, pedestrians, wheelchair users.

If the adjustment is difficult, you may postpone it and calculate the shortest path ignoring adjustments. Then if the shortest path contains any tricky edge (like stairs), you adjust the distance for that edge and repeat the whole calculation. So in the case that there are many stairs that are not on the shortest path anyway, you ignore them.

I wouldn't remove these edges from the graph, but just give them a reasonable penalty in the distance. Consider the situation where there is no way from A to B without stairs, but one stairs has ten steps and one has five steps. Or one path that is ten meters with stairs, and another that is ten miles without stairs.